# How to pass multiple params into display:column tag in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, tags, displaytag, param

I am trying to pass in multiple (3) parameters to a URL from `display:column` tag.
 I am trying to use code like this. but the object is passed as `null`.

```
<display:column class="nowrap" url="/secure/Edit.action"
                value="Edit" >
      <s:param  name="file.no"   value="#file.no" />
  <s:param  name="file.id"   value="#file.id" />
  <s:param  name="file.channel"   value="#file.channel" />
</display:column>
```

I have also tried using `%{file.no}` instead of `#` , but not worked.

Comment: s:param is used to pass parameters into struts2 tags, it does not know other tags and it is unlikely other tags are aware of it (display:).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<s:url id="editUrl" namespace="/secure" action="Edit"><s:param  name="file.plsid"   value="%{file.plsid}" /><s:param  name="file.clientno"   value="%{file.clientno}" />
<s:param  name="file.inschannel"   value="%{file.inschannel}" /></s:url> 
<display:column class="nowrap" url="<s:property value="%{editUrl}"/>" value="Edit" />
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have tried using the suggested way, but no luck....Is there any other way of passing the params? I have tried     "%{file.inschannel} too instead of this.

Comment: What's the problem? Edited some typo in showing url. I only use struts tags.

Comment: Also post `struts.xml` or annotated action config, I cannot distinguish servlet context path from the action namespace. Post the `Edit` action source code to get me know the names of the properties.

Comment: Your action properties doesn't adhere to java bean spec.

Comment: There's no s:display tag, there's s:url that you should add the s:param in the body.

Comment: am adding s:url and s:param, but getting null values into the action class however I pass the value ...

Comment: In the action you should create an instance of the `File` where to set the parameters: `private File file = new File();`

Comment: I already have private File file; and have its getters and setters in action class.

Comment: Can't help if you don't understand what I've talked above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem and I didnt have to make any java code changes/ changes to my action class etc.

Its just that I have added attr to the property value and that took care of it!

Thanks for your time.,